# Move from A to B with animation

Tags: react-native, animation, translate-animation

i want to move the view A with Animation to view B. but the problem is we don't have position of B, it's dynamic and depend on screen size. best way to do?

Comment: opacity bro, just increase the opacity on A and decrease it on B

Comment: @FaysalB no bro, i want to use transition from A to B not opacity